# XSD to XML Convert

Tags: xml, xsd

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?
I have XSD schema

```
<xs:complexType name="getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest" type="tns:tnEODICOBJECTSRequest" form="qualified"
minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="tnEODICOBJECTSRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="objectId" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Id объекта</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="classId" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Id класса (спраочника)</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="objectKod" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Код символьный</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This one XSD schema

My option XSD TO XML

```
<ns0:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS xmlns:ns0="http://service.siw.getcode.go/">
    <ns0:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
        <ns0:tnEODICOBJECTSRequest>     
            <objectId>574</objectId>     
            <classId>4000</classId>
        </ns0:tnEODICOBJECTSRequest>         
    </ns0:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
</ns0:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS>
```

It doesn't work.
What should I do?
What Am I doing wrong?

[My original xsd schema](https://dropmefiles.com/tJL6n)

Comment: [It doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a helpful problem description.

Comment: You have given us some data - a schema and an instance document - but you haven't said anything about what you are trying to do that doesn't work. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question to explain **what** doesn't work.

Comment: Pretty sure, it tells you, it expects `<objectKod />` which is `nillable` but not optional.

Comment: Got it. I attached it below https://dropmefiles.com/tJL6n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to post the full schema, but if your schema looks like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <!--Created with Liquid Studio 2021 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
   <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://service.siw.getcode.go/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://service.siw.getcode.go/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:complexType name="getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS">
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest" type="tns:tnEODICOBJECTSRequest" minOccurs="0" form="qualified" />
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="tnEODICOBJECTSRequest">
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="objectId" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
               <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Id объекта</xs:documentation>
               </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="classId" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
               <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Id класса (спраочника)</xs:documentation>
               </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="objectKod" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
               <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Код символьный</xs:documentation>
               </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="Root" type="tns:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS" />
   </xs:schema>
```

[image: Liquid XSD Diagram]

then your sample XML would look like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2021 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
   <tns:Root xmlns:tns="http://service.siw.getcode.go/" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://service.siw.getcode.go/ SO_67668466.xsd">
      <tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
         <tns:objectId>-3997</tns:objectId>
         <tns:classId>-12</tns:classId>
         <tns:objectKod>3720</tns:objectKod>
      </tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
   </tns:Root>
```

Note: In your XSD getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS is defined as a complexType, in order to use it you must define an element of type getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS (I created an element called 'root' in order to create a valid XML document).

**Update after schema was added**

Your schema is invalid.

```
  <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://service.go/" 
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             version="1.0" 
             targetNamespace="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/">
     <xs:element name="Reference12ASUResponse" type="tns:reference12ASUResponse"/>
```

It looks like `xmlns:tns="http://service.go/"` should be `xmlns:tns="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/"`.

I think another issue is that the schema does not specify `<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"` (which pretty much all schemas do), your schema then defines some elements as qualified, i.e. `TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest` specifies that its namespace should be qualified. This makes it quite tricky to work out which elements need a namespace alias. But in your case it looks like this is the valid XML for the schema (note the ns on `<tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>`, but not on `<objectId>`)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2021 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
  <tns:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS xmlns:tns="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/" 
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                            xsi:schemaLocation="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/ SO_67668466.xsd">
     <tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
        <objectId>-4486</objectId>
        <classId>2000</classId>
        <objectKod>-4247</objectKod>
        <objectKodstr>string</objectKodstr>
        <objectVname>string</objectVname>
        <objectName>string</objectName>
        <objectSname>string</objectSname>
        <refer>2060</refer>
        <s1>string</s1>
        <i1>-475</i1>
        <komm>string</komm>
        <corTip>string</corTip>
        <dateNd>2001-01-15T04:53:04.70</dateNd>
        <dateKd>2011-10-07T16:16:02.20</dateKd>
        <corTime>1993-10-18T10:43:28.61</corTime>
        <operId>-3192</operId>
        <dorNsi>string</dorNsi>
     </tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
  </tns:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS>
```

[image]

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980. --><xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://service.siw.getcode.go/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://service.siw.getcode.go/"></xs:schema>` I forget past

Comment: I try getting request.  I use SOAP UI 5.6  ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <tns:Root xmlns:tns="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
     <tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
         <tns:objectId>-3997</tns:objectId>
         <tns:classId>-12</tns:classId>
         <tns:objectKod>3720</tns:objectKod>
      </tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
   </tns:Root>

Comment: `Response `   <return xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</return>
         <Text xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<error version="1.0">
<errorCode value="100"/>
<errorMessage value="The processing instruction target matching &quot;[xX][mM][lL]&quot; is not allowed."/>
<errorStatusCode value="400"/>
</error>]]></Text>
      </NS1:GetBlockResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
`

Comment: Could you update your question to provide more information, its not clear what you are asking from what you have posted in the comments.

Comment: Yes. I update My question. I attached original schema

Comment: Thank you sir for you explain. but Im getting eror `<errorMessage value="ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: can not get xquery string"/>` what does this tell us?

Comment: Im thinking so. Thanks